# Using only the values of JSON data that is unmarshalled

Tags: json, go, slice, marshalling

I'm looking to take a list of ids and add them to a slice. However if I don't custom unmarshall the data, I cannot get to the values of the ids and it is just an array of JSON objects. And if I do custom unmarshall the data I want, I am told that I cannot append that slice-like array of data because it has a custom type from the structs I used to unmarshall.

I would prefer to only make the request once to get both the "data" and "meta" information from a rest API, I then unmarshall that data into the following:

```
{Data:[{Ids:39647} {Ids:39648} {Ids:39649} {Ids:39650} {Ids:39651} {Ids:39652} {Ids:39653} {Ids:39654} {Ids:39655} {Ids:39656} {Ids:39657} {Ids:39658} {Ids:39659} {Ids:39660} {Ids:39661} {Ids:39662} {Ids:39663} {Ids:39664} {Ids:39665} {Ids:39666} {Ids:39667} {Ids:39668} {Ids:39669} {Ids:39670} {Ids:39671} {Ids:39672} {Ids:39673}] Meta:{Metadata:{CurrentPage:3 TotalPages:656}}}
```

I would like to get the `Ids` in a slice like so:

```
[39647 39649 39650 ...]
```

Preferably without having to marshall and then unmarshall again, but beggars can't be choosers. This would then need to be of slice type `[]int` so that I can append it to another slice and use all standard library slice things with it.

Edit: It was requested I add the basic JSON Structure to the question.

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 38926
    },
    {
      "id": 38927
    },
    //... and so on.
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total": 163795,
      "current_page": 3,
      "total_pages": 81898
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON?

Comment: oops sorry, added @Wolfgang

Comment: Can you also include a minimal example of your problem in Go?  Including the results with and without custom unmarshal you describe?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a straight slice of int-"id",without unmarshalling the whole JSON, you could use a JSON parser library to do that, ex-https://github.com/tidwall/gjson.

```
package main

import "github.com/tidwall/gjson"

json := `{
 "data":[
   {
      "id":38926
   },
   {
      "id":38927
   }
 ],
 "meta":{
   "pagination":{
      "total":163795,
      "current_page":3,
      "total_pages":81898
    }
  }
}`

func main() {
    value := gjson.Get(json, "data.#.id")
    println(value.Array()) // etc
}
```